# How to run Ionic App against a localhost API (Dev App)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, localhost, ionic-devapp

I'm trying to simulate my Ionic app with the "Ionic DevApp" in my iOS device but, I can't connect to the localhost api that is running in my computer from the device.
I've changed the API request endpoint to my computer's local IP address but  nothing changes. 
This the URL example I'm using:

```
http://192.168.0.145:8080/countries
```

This is the full provider:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';   

@Injectable()
export class CountryProvider {

private url: string; 

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  this.url = "http://192.168.0.145:8080/countries";
}

getCountries() {
  return this.http.get(this.url);
}
```

Of course, It's working correctly if I run the app in the computer browser.
I've checked the same URL on the iOS device browser and it's fine.

Comment: have you tried to open this url `http://192.168.0.145:8080/countries` in browser?

Comment: Is your IOS device and your computer connected on the Same network??

Comment: I've opened the same url from the computer and iOS device browser and it's ok, it shows me the data correctly, as expected. @un.spike

Comment: my IOS device is on the same network, I'm using the Ionic Dev App to connect and run de app. @AshishRanjan